# How to delete a node from nested model set with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My question is what is the right approach to delete a node in a nested model set using PHP and MYSQL. As far as i am concern, i have to decrement all left values greater than the node to delete’s left value by 2..However i am so confuse with the next steps. You answers will be very much appreciated.

This is my function:

```
public function deleteNode($id,$left,$right)
{
    //?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solutions from Mike Hillyers

```
public function delete_node($id)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT node.label
        FROM menus AS node,menus AS parent
        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rft AND parent.id = $id
        GROUP BY node.label
        ORDER BY node.lft
    ");

    if($query->num_rows() > 1)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query("LOCK TABLE $this->table WRITE");
        $this->db->query("SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rft, @myWidth := rft - lft + 1 FROM $this->table WHERE id = $id");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE lft = @myLeft");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $this->table SET rft = rft - 1, lft = lft - 1 WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $this->table SET rft = rft - 2 WHERE rft > @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $this->table SET lft = lft - 2 WHERE lft > @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query("LOCK TABLE $this->table WRITE");
        $this->db->query("SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rft, @myWidth := rft - lft + 1 FROM $this->table WHERE id = $id");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $this->table SET rft = rft - @myWidth WHERE rft > @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $this->table SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight");
        $this->db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }    
    }

}
```

Comment: The first query will check if the subject for deletion has child. It has child it will use transaction in the else statement if none use the other one